# Spring boot 2 application slow start up, due to 'tomcatPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-boot-actuator

I am facing a slow down issue at the time of start-up after moving from SpringBoot1 to SpringBoot2 on a Java8 supported application.

It takes 35-40 min to start and around 15 on a single bean creating name 'tomcatPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider'.

> 07/08/2019 15:46:05.382 DEBUG
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:
>   [main] [{}] - Autowiring by type from bean name
>   'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.jdbc.DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration$DataSourcePoolMetadataMetricsConfiguration'
>   via constructor to bean named 'tomcatPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider'
>   07/08/2019 16:00:03.649 DEBUG
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:
>   [main] [{}] - Creating shared instance of singleton bean
>   'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.jdbc.DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration'

```
import com.expedia.lodging.booking.metrics.annotation.EnableApplicationMetrics;
import expedia.content.solutions.metrics.spring.EnableMetrics;
import expedia.content.solutions.poke.spring.support.EnablePoke;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.jdbc.DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;


@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.class})
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath:spring-config.xml"})
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableScheduling
@EnablePoke
@EnableMetrics
@EnableApplicationMetrics
public class Application {

  @Value("${http.port}")
  private int httpPort;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
    ServletRegistrationBean register = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
    register.addUrlMappings("/*", "/ping");  // Allow root level ping.
    return register;
  }}
```

Comment: Can you take some thread dumps during that 15 minute period and add them to your question? It would be useful to know what the main thread is doing during that time.

Comment: I fixed this problem after reading SpringBoot documents for a day or two
So apparently Spring Boot does a lot of auto-configuration that may or may not be needed, excluding unwanted autoconfigure classes may help
in my case this helped

```@SpringBootApplication(exclude ={DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.class})```

It just makes actuator/health take more response time